# Start Word without Add Ins

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office-addins

Is there any way to start MS Word (**only this instance**) without Add Ins?
I only find a way to disable the Add Ins complete.

Answer (score 5):

From the [Word command line switches documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210565/en-us), you can use the `/a` switch to "prevent add-ins and global templates from being loaded automatically.":

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\Winword.exe" /a
```

You could also start Word in Safe Mode with the `/safe` switch:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\Winword.exe" /safe
```