# OLE: embed microsoft word without add ins

Tags: java, ms-word, swt, ole

As described here [Start Word without Add Ins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203898/start-word-without-add-ins), it is possible to start ms word without "add ins" or in "safe mode".
I was wondering if this is also possible in my SWT application, embedding word using OLE?

Right now I do the following:

```
new OleControlSite(clientFrame, SWT.NONE, "Word.Document")
```

Maybe there is another program id, similar to "Word.Document" which forces word to start without add ins?
Maybe there is a property or setting which accomplishes this?

Answer (score 0):

This code, in the eclipse forum, disables the add-ins after the word is loaded:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/221747/

```
int idAddIns = application.getIDsOfNames(new String[] {"COMAddIns"})[0];
Variant addInsVar = application.getProperty(idAddIns);
OleAutomation addIns = addInsVar.getAutomation();

int countID = addIns.getIDsOfNames(new String[] {"Count"})[0];
Variant countVariant = addIns.getProperty(countID);

int addInsItemID = addIns.getIDsOfNames(new String[] {"Item"})[0];
for (int i = 1; i <= countVariant.getInt(); i++) {
    Variant addInsItemVariant = addIns.invoke(addInsItemID, new Variant[] {new Variant(i)});
    OleAutomation addInsItem = addInsItemVariant.getAutomation();

    int addInsItemConnectID = addInsItem.getIDsOfNames(new String[] { "Connect" })[0];
    if (addInsItem.getProperty(addInsItemConnectID).getBoolean()) {
        int addInsItemNameID = addInsItem.getIDsOfNames(new String[] { "ProgId" })[0];
        Variant addInsItemNameVariant = addInsItem.getProperty(addInsItemNameID);
        String name = addInsItemNameVariant.getString();                
        addInsItem.setProperty(addInsItemConnectID, new Variant(false));
    }
}
```

Warning: It also disables the add-ins outside of your application, so you might want to enable it after closing the application.